# Is My Varnish Install Working or Not?

Tags: drupal-7, varnish

I am test running Drupal 7 on a local Centos/LAMP VM, not connected to the Internet, with Varnish and the Varnish Module installed.

I can't tell if Varnish is working or not.  As I cannot put my instance on the Internet, I cannot use http://www.isvarnishworking.com/ to test.

Chrome returns the following at http://localhost/data:

1st run:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 07 Sep 2016 17:22:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Language: en
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Etag: "1473268932-1"
Last-Modified: Wed, 07 Sep 2016 17:22:12 GMT
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 7579
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Varnish: 162
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

2nd run:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 07 Sep 2016 17:23:01 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Language: en
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Etag: "1473268981-1"
Last-Modified: Wed, 07 Sep 2016 17:23:01 GMT
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 7583
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Varnish: 917543
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

curl -Ij http://localhost/data returns the following:

1st run:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 07 Sep 2016 17:25:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Language: en
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Last-Modified: Wed, 07 Sep 2016 17:25:27 GMT
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Varnish: 786539
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
ETag: W/"1473269127-1"
Connection: keep-alive
```

2nd run:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 07 Sep 2016 17:25:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) PHP/5.4.16
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=60
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Language: en
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Generator: Drupal 7 (http://drupal.org)
Last-Modified: Wed, 07 Sep 2016 17:25:27 GMT
Vary: Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Varnish: 917560 786540
Age: 26
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
ETag: W/"1473269127-1"
Connection: keep-alive
```

Here is part of my /etc/varnish/default.vcl:

```
# Default backend definition. Set this to point to your content server.
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
}
```

Here is part of my /etc/httpd/httpd.conf:

```
Listen 8080
NameVirtualHost *:8080
```

Finally, here are my admin/config/development/performance settings:

```
CACHING
Cache pages for anonymous users  (checked)
Cache blocks (checked)
Minimum cache lifetime: none
Expiration of cached pages: 1 min
```

It seems like Varnish is working for curl but not for Chrome.  From what I have read about Varnish under Drupal, I should be seeing a two values for X-Varnish, which I see on my second curl run but do not see in Chrome.  I don't know if I should see Drupal cache as a HIT because doesn't Varnish provide the cache?  Not seeing anything that says HIT for Varnish, however.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

In response to Ronald's question, here are the Chrome Request Headers:

```
    GET /data HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost
    Connection: keep-alive
    Cache-Control: max-age=0
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
    Cookie: has_js=1
    If-None-Match: "1473274273-1"
```

Comment: what does the request sent by chrome look like. Does it include cookies?

Comment: Hi Ronald.  I have added the Chrome Request Headers in the post in answer to your question.

Comment: I do not know anything about Drupal but Varnish on its on with the default configuration does not cache anything with a cookie. One has to remove the Cookie-Header on the request and the Set-Cookie-Header on the response in the VCL for Varnish to cache.

Comment: I would think that Drupal would send the correct header (with or without cookies) to acquire a page that Varnish could cache since I am using the Drupal Varnish module.  I still don't know if my problem is Drupal, Varnish, or both.